# Using sockets to log a button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am very new to web sockets. I would like to be able to create a simple web app that logs the number of times a button has been clicked:

```
<button>click</button>
<div id="counter"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('div#counter').html(function(i, val) {
            return val*1 + 1
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I know I can update the div with a value using JavaScript/jQuery, but how can I store this via plaintext/database and display a live output of the number of times the button has been clicked.

For example, if `browser A` is open and the current count is `5` and `browser B` opens and clicks the button, the count will update to `6` on both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need some WebSocket server backend and  persistent storage there. Then you need a mechanism to notify the backend of the click plus a mechanism to notify all connected browsers of the update.

For the notifcations, this is a perfect fit for Publish/Subscribe (PubSub).

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://autobahn.ws/js/tutorials/pubsub/) for an example how to do this using WebSockets and AutobahnJS in the browser and AutobahnPython on a server. (No guarantee you'll be able to execute the demo directly as described at the moment since big changes are underway around the Autobahn project, and updates are underway, but it will give you an idea of the basic pattern.)

Depending on what kind of backend language you're using, you may want to look at [alternative implementations](http://wamp.ws/implementations/wamp1/) of WAMP, the protocol that the above libraries use for the PubSub pattern. There are quite a few, and one of them might fit your need.

(Full disclosure: I work for Tavendo, the project maintainers for the Autobahn WebSocket projects.)

PS: Here's [code for a demo](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbardemo/tree/master/web/demo/vote) doing exactly what you want, including persisting the backend data in an Oracle database. However, this is definitely currently inoperable while work on the next release of Crossbar.io continues.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a server-side language, pure js won't do, on php i would do

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
   <?php
        $conection="connection values";
        $sql="update some_table set somevalue=somevalue+1";
        //execute query

    ?>
}
</script>
```

or of you dont want to have the php code and datebase connection on the same file you can invoke it like this

```
<script>
   function myFunction(){
       $.get("somepage.php");
       return false;

   }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm hoping to use socket.io/node.js. With PHP you have to connect to the database to call for the data and this will not be consistent in all currently open browsers without web sockets.